# AppleScript try loop With delay

Tags: applescript, try-catch, delay, repeat

I want to Repeat With try , if error delay, if success exit repeat, but there it's doesn't delay
the code is

```
repeat with once in 10
    try
         set ....
         eixt repeat
    on error
         delay(3)
    end try
end repeat
```

I don't know how to fix it, please help me

Comment: i just want to reset something when error

Answer (score 0):

Here's some improvement to your code, and it works fine:

```
repeat with once from 1 to 10
    try
        set x to onc -- erros because misspelled
        exit repeat
    on error
        delay (3)
    end try
end repeat
```